# Present your cases for a [case-study]!

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we allow case studies? For example, should we look at the practices and results that other organizations or projects have taken, and sort of make case studies out of there. I'm proposing that we create a dedicated tag for these case studies.

A [case-study](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case-study) tag on main would allow people to find information, and examples of Open Source. On the sites that I have helped pioneer (but sadly didn't make it), the tag works extremely well.

Comment: I like the idea of case studies as long as they don't become an excuse for other questions to become broad and meandering.

Comment: I think we would need a set of rules for what constitutes an on topic case study, with very clear dos and don'ts.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see these, but people here would have to accept that they are a slightly different genre of question.

In a case study, a more detailed answer *may* be required, and the questions may be a little broader. However, if people can accept that, these would be good questions to see. I think they'd generate a lot of interest and voting, which are always good for our stats.

We may also need to police the tag a little: we can't have people using it as an excuse to ask a question that's just far too broad, nor can we have people closing every question on the tag because it's too broad - by their nature, they will be a little broader.

Comment: I'm guessing that one step would be writing a comprehensive tag wiki and excerpt?

Comment: Indeed it would, which I'd be happy to do

Comment: I would suggest one, but I can't edit tags, that same [bug](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-tag-posts-really-deleted)...

Comment: @Zizouz212 the edits do go through, it's just an apparent glitch

Comment: No, it won't let me suggest for anything... Tag wise. Even if it's new or old. Strangely, I can approve tag edits...

Comment: @Zizouz212 Go try it. I'll tell you if I find it in the suggested edits queue.

Comment: It won't even bring me to the edit page. Clicking on the *improve this wiki...* leads me to the same page from my post: Why I've never been active with tags lately ;(

Comment: Is that a new separate bug then? Has it been raised elsewhere?

Comment: I've raised it here: http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-tag-posts-really-deleted